# Can I upload a file without the FileUpload control's attached textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

In my ASP.NET project, I want to add a facility to my page so that when the user clicks a button, a 'browse file' dialog box directly opens up. After he selects the file in the dialog box, I want to save that image on the server, and update an imagebox based on that selection.

Is there some sort of dynamic 'browse for file' type dialog box that I can use?

Comment: Do you mean a functionality such that the textbox in the FileUpload control should not be activated? Why not just set the textbox to readonly?

Comment: It's a matter of visual style. I want there to be just a link button under a user's profile pic. And when that button is clicked, I want the dialog box to appear, and upon selection of a new image, the image box is immediately updated.

Comment: T__T help?
Looks like I better implement some workaround v__v

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this demo](http://vremenno.net/examples/updated-file-input-styling/).

Article (http://vremenno.net/js/javascript-snippets-plus-new-file-input/) is in Russian, but you can always use Google Translate.

Source code available here: (http://vremenno.net/examples/updated-file-input-styling/UpdatedFileInputStyling.zip)

Sorry for ugly links: this is my first post and I'm not allowed to use more than one link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I ended up using the FileUpload control anyway. I made it so that when the user clicks the "change photo" button, the previously invisible FU control becomes visible and the button's caption changes to "OK! Update pic!".

Based on the button's caption it either reveals the FU control, or saves the file present in the FU and hides it again.

Working on a small project after which I will not touch web dev for a long while, so I'm not sure about investing time in learning javascript bits.

Thanks anyway!